# List is null in inheritance (C#, Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I am sorry if this is a bit basic, but i can't figure out the problem.

I have three classes:

```
public class ClassA : MonoBehavior
{
     public List<T> list;  
     
     void Start()
       {
        list = new List<T>; 
        //then fill the list. 
       }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
  void DoesSomething()
  {
     if(list.Count != 0)
  }
} 

public interface IClassB { ClassB classB { get; set;} }; 
public class ClassC: MonoBehaviour, IClassB
{
   public ClassB classB { get; set;}
    
   void Start()
   {
     classB = new ClassB();
   }
    
   public void OnButtonClick()
   {
      classB.DoesSomething();
   }
}
```

Now when i call the DoesSomething() function in ClassC, i get an null exception in the line where i check the list count in ClassB, even though i initialized and filled the list in the start funciton of ClassA. I debugged it to check if it initializes properly and it does.

So maybe i am missing something regarding interfaces or Unity and C# inheritance in general.
I appreciate the help and thanks in advance!

Comment: `ClassA.Start()` is **`private`** so I don't see where you would ever end up calling it.

Comment: @dbc [`MonoBehaviour.Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) is invoked as a message by the Unity framework itself. In this case though OP creates the instance using `new` which is absolutely "illegal" for any type derived from `Component` ;) See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Your `ClassB` is a `MonoBehaviour`.

**You never instantiate a `MonoBehaviour` (or in general anything deriving from [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html)) using the `new` keyword! Never!**

[image]

Humor aside, Unity actually should throw a warning about it. It makes no sense. Every `MonoBehaviour` belongs to a certain instance of `GameObject`. And therefore there are only three valid ways of how to create an instance:

- Use the constructor of [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-ctor.html) in order to create a new empty `GameObject` with according component(s) attached.
- Use [`AddComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) on an existing `GameObject` in order to do that, add that component to the `GameObject`.
- Use [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) to either clone an existing `GameObject` or instantiate a prefab instance with according component attached.

Since creating an instance via `new` is highly "illegal" also none of the `Start` methods will be called.

---

So since it seems your class should **not** be attached to a certain `GameObject` anyway but you are going to create an instance via `new` remove the `MonoBehaviour` inheritance and rather use a proper class.

```
public class ClassA
{
    // And then why not simply initialize the list by default?
    // that avoids these kind of initialization problems already right from the beginning
    public List<T> list = new List<T>(); 
     
    // And do the rest of your initialization stuff in a proper constructor
    public ClassA()
    { 
        //then fill the list. 
    }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public void DoesSomething()
    {
         if(list.Count != 0) { }
    }
}
```

Then later again you could/should initialize the property right away (since c# 6)

```
public ClassB classB { get; set;} = new ClassB();
```

---

**If** however your `ClassA` (and thereby `ClassB` actually **shall** be a `MonoBehaviour` then you don't want to use `new` but get an instance in a different way. See before...

Still, since `Start` is called as a **message** it is only called on the last implementation so only for `ClassB`.

So for nested inherited `MonoBehaviour` it is recommended to make the Unityessage methods like `Awake`, `Start` etc to be `virtual` and override them in the derived classes like

```
public class ClassA : MonoBehaviour
{
    // And then why not simply initialize the list by default?
    // that avoids these kind of initialization problems already right from the beginning
    public List<T> list = new List<T>(); 
     
    protected virtual void Start()
    { 
        //then fill the list. 
    }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();

        // Additional stuff specific for this type
    }

    public void DoesSomething()
    {
         if(list.Count != 0) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @derHugo! I have changed the list to initialize at declaration. That helped with the null reference, but it hasn't solved my problem entirely. I want ClassA to be a MonoBehaviour and ClassC too. They are both attached to a game object. Class B should not necessarily be attached to a gameObject that's why I am trying it that way. The problem now Is, that ClassB has an empty list, even though I filled it on start in ClassA. So my question kind of stands: What am I missing regarding inheritance?

Comment: @Temeos as already said: You do **not** create new instances using `new`. If your `ClassA` is a `MonoBehaviour` then so is `ClassB` since it inherits from `ClassA` ... So it is unclear what you are doing exactly ...

Comment: I have a script with ClassA, which i attach to a gameObject. This script holds some information that can be modified in editor and all that stuff. I have ClassB that has some methods, to e.g. save stuff from ClassA into an xml format. ClassC has a bunch of OnGui() methods to build a simple UI that calls the methods in ClassB. The reason I am doing things the way I am doing them, is because I thought it would be nicer to make all the connections inheritance based, instead of attaching all the scripts to a GO and using FindObjectOfType<> all the time.

Comment: Now, I know I could go about it a different way, but at this point my curiosity got the better of me and I'd like to figure out how to do it the way I am trying to do it. I understand, that the problem is me using the "new" keyword, but what would be the alternative, if not FindObjectOfType<>()?